# Armature not bending with connected bones

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

In pose mode, I try to rotate a bone, but instead it rotates all the bones that are connected to it.

How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: This seems to the root bone  (parent of all other bones) it is used to move a whole rigged model. You should add more details e.g. screen-shots with annotations on how the armature is setup.

Comment: In addition to annotated screen shots, you may need to upload a copy of your ~.blend file to [Blend.exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), or a similar site.

Comment: Sounds like the bone might have an ik constraint?

Comment: @sambler I will upload pictures as soon as possible, but if you don't mind me asking, what is an ik constraint? This is my first time making armatures.

Comment: bone constraints are available while in pose mode and have their own icon in the properties window - it is a bone and two little chain links. [Difference between ik and fk](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/24633/935). If you made the armature you may have enabled auto ik (a checkbox in the toolbar in the options tab) Shift I is also a shortcut to adding an ik constraint.

Comment: @sambler Okay I uploaded a picture, and as you can see the bones are not bending when rotated. I checked and there is no ik constraints.

Comment: @sambler Wait, is it possible that bones can be in the wrong direction?

Comment: A bone has a head and a tail, the head is normally the pivot point unless you are using the 3dcursor. Using octahedral as the display type for the armature makes it clear which is which, useful when starting out and finding problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the bones were upside down, so they were not moving correctly. When bones are upside down, the only thing that will rotate correctly are the ones on the top because if done correctly, the ones on top move all the bones that are connected to it.

Comment: please add more to your answer, to make it more useful for future viewers.